# print only rows that has latest non empty cell that starts with the word "Failed" on a CSV file in Linux

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to print the table only if non-empty latest column that starts with the word "Failed"on a CSV file in Linux..

My input -

```
Name,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Mon
Linux,Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup,,,,,Failed Fullbackup
Unix,,,,Failed Fullbackup,,
Windows,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Successfull Fullbackup
MAC,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup
Solaris,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup,,
```

My output should be:

```
Name,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Mon
Linux,Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup,,,,,Failed Fullbackup
Unix,,,,Failed Fullbackup,,
MAC,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup
```

Comment: Would be better if you just could format your question neat.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Both the second row and the final two in your example would qualify.

Comment: You don't indicate 'Successfull Fullbackup"  and "Failed Fullbackup" are the only possible entries after the first column. CSV files in general can have multi-line cell values, making parsing with grep/awk cumbersome if not impossible. You seem to be presenting a TSV file, but you should use a CSV, as we cannot see the tabs which are gobbled by the system, thus not see for sure how many cells any of the lines might have.

Comment: Anthon I got your point, pasted input & output in CSV format

Comment: @user81341: Why `Unix` line is shown, Solaris isn't?

Comment: So now the field delimiters are commas *and* spaces (and a semicolon)? This is not helpful: voting to close...

Comment: Why unix is - latest non empty cell is starting with "Failed" Why not Solaris is - latest non empty cell is not starting with "Failed" and is starting with "Successfull".  Please note -               "Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup" is one cell.

Comment: Hi Gnouc, "Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup"  this is the latest non empty. we consider under "Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup" as Sucessfull only.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 1b -e $'/[\t,]Failed[^\t,]*[\t,]*$/!d'
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, "Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup" this entire is a cell at 2nd row 2nd column, i want to skip this also. on a whole i need to print only rows that has latest non empty cell that  starts with the word "Failed" I will change question.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also for your information "," or tab would be the delimiter for each cell in a row.

Comment: Am not getting the proper output when ran on main file. Please find the new i/p and o/p tagged in the question.

Comment: @user81341, works for me on your sample.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what all this is about, but those were some long lines - it was hard to interpret for me. So, I did this:

```
sed 's/,S[^,]*/,A/g;s/,Fa[^,]*/,F/g
' <<\DATA
Name,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Mon
Linux,Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup,,,,,Failed Fullbackup
Unix,,,,Failed Fullbackup,,
Windows,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Successfull Fullbackup
MAC,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup
Solaris,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup,,
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Name,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Mon
Linux,A,,,,,F
Unix,,,,F,,
Windows,F,F,F,F,F,A
MAC,F,F,F,F,F,F
Solaris,F,F,F,A,,
```

I don't know if it answers your question or not, but it sure makes it a lot easier for me to read. Report cards I understand. And by the way, someone should really have a look at that Mac. *So much potential...*

Comment: Sorry this A was flagged as not an A. I now see you did A it with the `sed` at the top. My bad 8-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle 'print if $. == 1 or (grep {$_} @F)[-1] =~ /^Failed/' file
Name,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Mon
Linux,Successfull Fullbackup; Failed Fullbackup,,,,,Failed Fullbackup
Unix,,,,Failed Fullbackup,,
MAC,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup,Failed Fullbackup
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of variations on Stéphane’s answer:

```
(line; grep $'[\t,]Failed[^\t,]*[\t,]*$') < input
```

The `(line; grep …)` construct comes in very handy;
for example, for filtering the output from `ps`. 
If your system doesn’t have the `line` command,

```
(read x; echo "$x"; grep $'[\t,]Failed[^\t,]*[\t,]*$') < input
```

should work, too.  Alternatively,

```
grep -E $'^Name,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Mon$|[\t,]Failed[^\t,]*[\t,]*$' input
```

Comment: Cat file | awk -F"," '{for ( x=NF ; x>1 ; x-- ) { if ( $x ~ /^Failed/ ) { x = 0 ; print }  ; if ( $x ~ /^Successful/ ) x = 0  } }'                       ........ This worked for me...... thanks everyone.

Comment: This does not, strictly speaking, answer the question that you asked, because you never *said* that every field (other than the first row and the first column) begins with either “Failed” or “Successful” – you said (in effect) that every field is blank, begins with “Failed”, or is something else. For instance, according to *what you said* about your data, `Cray,Failed,Failed,,,,OK` would be a valid line that should not be output, but your solution (above) *would* print it. We don’t expect you to post all your real data; we ask you to *describe* your problem and post a representative example.

Comment: But also, you almost never need to say `cat file | (command)`. This is known as a [“useless use of cat”](http://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat), which is even [discussed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_use_of_cat#Useless_use_of_cat). With `awk`, as with most other Unix & Linux commands, you can say `awk (awk_options) '(awk_script)' file` or `awk < file (awk_options) '(awk_script)'`.

Comment: That said, if you believe that you have an answer to your question, you should post it ***as an answer***, not as a comment, and especially not on a comment on somebody else’s answer that is totally different from your answer. And, if you provide a few words of explanation, people might even vote for it and give you some reputation.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat file | awk -F"," \
    '{for ( x=NF ; x>1 ; x-- ) { if ( $x ~ /^Failed/ ) { x = 0 ; print } ; \
    if ( $x ~ /^Successful/ ) x = 0 } }'
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Can you please explain what this is doing?